# Ícones somem ao dar zoom no mapa do google

Tags: javascript, google-maps

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP, via JS inseri no mapa do Google alguns ícones, onde eu vou passando o mouse sobre os endereços que estão em uma lista vai dando zoom no mapa, porém ao repetir o zoom in/out os ícones somem, já acorreu isso com alguém daqui?